# Flutter 'cannot find symbol'

Tags: flutter, symbols

What can I do to fix this issue, when trying to debug on android phone OR emulator?

http://prntscr.com/pp43k4

Ive tried reinstalling whole flutter, and still the same issue.
the project is on flutter version 1.7.8. Tried going to latest versions, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` to clear the build artifacts - If the project was copied from another computer, or if you were using different version of flutter, that could help.